# the same A as Verb + Subject

Tags: grammar, verbs, subjects

While reading a book, I found:

> Objective-C supports the same conventions as does C.

I've thought "... as C does" is correct. For example,

> As time goes by, we come to forget almost everything.

Why were subject and verb replaced in the first sentence?